# "Ich hätte gern Herrn Müller / mit Herrn Müller gesprochen."

Tags: usage

Auf dem Blatt "Redemittel zum Telefonieren" stehen folgende Sätze:

> a) Ich hätte gern *Herrn Müller* gesprochen.
>
> b) Ich hätte gern *mit Herrn Müller* gesprochen.

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen dem Satz mit der Präposition *mit* und direktem Akkusativ oder können beide Sätze als synonym verwendbar angesehen werden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die Sätze sagen i.W. das gleiche aus, es gibt lediglich Nuancen in der Höflichkeit:

a) Ich hätte gern Herrn Müller gesprochen. - Dieser Satz beinhaltet, dass die Person, mit der du gerade sprichst, dich weiterverbinden kann. Außerdem erwartest du geradezu, das sie dies auch tut. Der Ton ist ein wenig "aggressiv". [Etwas, das man vielleicht sagt, wenn man sich schon durch verschiedene Instanzen gekämpft hat und glaubt kurz vor dem Ziel zu sein.]

b) Ich hätte gern mit Herrn Müller gesprochen. - Dieser Satz informiert die Person am Telefon lediglich darüber, dass du mit Herrn Müller sprechen möchtest. Es ist in geringerem Maße impliziert, dass du weiterverbunden werden möchtest, falls die Person am Telefon überhaupt dazu in der Lage ist. Daher ist dieser Satz höflicher. [Dieser Satz könnte am Anfang eines solchen Kampfes durch die Instanzen stehen, wenn man noch glaubt, dass alles sehr schnell gehen wird.]

Comment: The question was asked in German, so please answer it either in German or bilingually, not just in English. Die Frage war auf deutsch gestellt, also bitte beantworte sie auch auf deutsch oder zweisprachig, aber nicht nur auf englisch. Inhaltlich ist Deine Antwort korrekt.

Comment: Da beide Sätze im Konj. II mit 'bitte' formuliert sind, handelt es sich beide Male um höflich und zurückhaltend vorgetragene Wunschsätze. Tatsächlich ist die Formulierung ohne Präposition eine Spur direkter. Vielleicht gibt es auch einen kleinen Bedeutungsunterschied: _Jemanden sprechen wollen_ impliziert etwas deutlicher, dass der Sprecher einen bestimmten Gesprächsanlass bzw. ein Thema hat, das er besprochen haben will. _Mit jemandem sprechen wollen_ assoziiert eher eine Bitte um Zugangsberechtigung zum Gesprächspartner, auch ohne geschäftlichen Anlass. Für mich wäre Satz 1 'normaler'.